# What are current political activities to promote YouTubers' community interests?

Tags: policy

In 2019, there has been a declaration of partnership between [IG Metall and YouTubers' trade union](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/30621/does-a-trade-union-of-youtubers-exist).

Have there been further political activities to actually promote YouTubers' community interests, either in Germany or in other countries since then?